# How does Incense work?

Tags: pokemon-go

The item "Incense" has the description:

> Incense with a mysterious fragrance that lures wild Pokémon to your location for 30 minutes.

Does this mean that if I stay still, over the next 30 mins Pokémon will come to me, rather than me walking around to find them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does moving affect incense?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273872/does-moving-affect-incense)

Comment: @Mooz This question was asked and got an upvoted answer before [Does moving affect incense?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/273872/4797) I believe the duplicate closure should be the other way around.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a part from game code that defines how incense works.

Simply, it spawns 1 Pokémon when you walk 200 meters (1 minute minimum between 200m movement spawns) or wait every 5 minute while not moving.

You can stay still and get 6 Pokémon, or get up to 30 Pokémon by moving.

[image: Info from game code]

Comment: Source of that code is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf

Comment: So to get a spawn per minute, you have to travel at 12 km/h (~7.5 mph)?

Answer (score 15):

> In your Bag you start out with two Incenses. These attract Pokémon to your trainer – you get an encounter roughly every five minutes. Each incense lasts for half an hour, and you don’t have to walk around to get encounters to happen with the Incense!

Saw this on a Pokémon go tips page so, I'm assuming if you do stand still you'll encounter a few Pokémon.

Comment: I would argue that it's up to chance where they spawn. I used 2 Incense and spent the next hour in the same spot with no encounters. However, the amount of Pokémon available in my vicinity went from 2-4 to nearly 10 at any given time while the Incense was in effect

Comment: I can vouch that after several uses of incense, this description accurately describes what I have experienced. You get an encounter roughly every 5 minutes, without moving.

Comment: @Ben There is a bug that prevents incense from working if your phone is not set to trust the network time. Have you checked if this is the case for you?

Answer (score 0):

An incense still lets you catch the pokemon that appear in the original syntax will still show up, but more will show up. The ones that have a pink "mist" around them means they have been attracted by the incense.

Comment: The original syntax?

Comment: what do u mean?