# Does moving affect incense?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I have incense active is there a difference in standing still or actively moving around? Would moving around make the incense ineffective or increase its effectiveness in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does.

This is a part from game code that defines how incense works.

Simply, it spawns 1 Pokémon when you walk 200 meters (1 minute minimum between 200m movement spawns) or wait every 5 minute while not moving.

You can stay still and get 6 Pokémon, or get up to 30 Pokémon by moving.

[image: Info from game code]

Comment: Source of that code is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf

Answer (score 0):

No, moving doesn't affect effectiveness and the Pokemon will always spawn directly on you, moving or staying still.

Answer (score 0):

Incense doesn't attract the Pokemon around you. It simply spawns additional ones (roughly about 5 extra an hour). It doesn't make a difference if you're walking or standing still.

Remember that Incense only makes these Pokemon appear for you and not for others. If you want to share the additional Pokemon you'll have to use the [Lure Module](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Lure_Module).

Answer (score 0):

it does effect it,

have somebody drive a car for you at 50km/h or so and use incense,

while standing stil i had 5 pokemon.

while my friend driving i had 24 pokemon. tho out of those 24 i could only catch 7.   >.<

you can clearly see a difference of incense spawning pokemon as they stay on map longer and have a pink smoke around them. so it were not normal wild pokemon.