# Can Pokemon move from their initial spawn location? If they don't, then what does the lure do?

Tags: pokemon-go

At first I thought the grass flying up in the sky and then flying up at a different spot is indicating that a Pokemon has moved around.

But when I walked past the Pokemon twice, they appear at the same spot, and another cellphone and account show the same location too.  So do Pokemons not move at all?  If so, then what does a lure do, if it won't move the Pokemons over... does it "move" the newly spawned Pokemons closer to the lure?

Answer (score 2):

No, Pokémon don't "move". They spawn in a static location for a period of time, then despawn if not found.

Similar to [incense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272667/how-does-incense-work), what lures do is cause a Pokémon to spawn at regular intervals within the range of the PokéStop that the lure has been applied to, for a period of time.

Comment: Interesting... So a lure or incense can be better thought of as a spawner...

Comment: Basically, yeah.